# Rails td cell link with instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this link:

```
<%= link_to "#{x.name}", { :controller => 'pages', :action =>
'berufsschule', :given_user => x.name} , :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
```

I want it to be a clickable table cell. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this via CSS. Create a class something like this:

```
a.cell_link {display: block; width: 100%; margin: 2em auto;}
```

And then add it in to your `:class => "btn btn-danger"`section; e.g. `:class => "btn btn-danger cell_link`.

Not knowing your table or UI needs you may find the margin section un-needed or incorrect.